# Добавить \n к ответу в определенных местах

Tags: java, android

Есть ответ сервера JSon со временем работы, в частности такого вида.

```
info_worktime":"Пн 9 00 17 30 12 30 13 15|Вт 9 00 17 30 12 30 13 15|Ср 9 00 17 30 12 30 13 15"
```

Вопрос как добавить вместо/или за разделителем перенос на новую строку?
Что бы каждый день был с новой строки а не разделен знаком `|`

Код геттера:

```
@SerializedName("info_worktime")
private String infoWorktime;
public String getInfoWorktime() {
    return infoWorktime;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы заменить строку нужно использовать [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-):

```
String infoWorktime = "Пн 9 00 17 30 12 30 13 15|Вт 9 00 17 30 12 30 13 15|Ср 9 00 17 30 12 30 13 15";
String correctString = infoWorktime.replace('|', '\n');
System.out.println(correctString);
```

[`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) принимает регулярное выражение, что в данном случае не требуется. В регулярных выражениях `|` используется как оператор «или», что, по-видимому, сбивает с толку парсер.

Comment: если критично время, можно использовать символы, а не строки: `('|', '\n')`

Comment: @MikhailIonkin да, Вы правы. Пожалуй, лучше использовать вариант с char.

Answer (score 5):

Просто замените символы:

```
String correctString = data.getInfoWorktime().replaceAll("\|", "\n");
```

Comment: Почему то добавляет в таком случает после каждого пробела, делаю в геттере:    public String getInfoWorktime() {
            String correctString = infoWorktime.replaceAll("|", "\n");
            return correctString;
        }  Получается каждая буква на новой строчке

Comment: @Романыч, попробуйте обновлённый код - я там экранировал палку